# "Blätterkreis", "Dornenkreis", "Herzkreis", in Englisch

Tags: translation, compounds, orthography, german

I need to translate the three terms - in the heading - into Englisch.

Blätterkreis: with `Blätter` I mean the leafs that fall down from trees. Is `Leafcircle` the correct translation?

Dornenkreis: Is `Thorncircle` correct?

Herzenkreis: Is `Heartcircle` correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leafcircle is not a word used in English. You should say "ring of leaves", "ring of thorns", or "ring of hearts". The more literal "circle of leaves" is also fine.

In particular examples there may be more appropriate terms: for example Caesar wore a "laurel wreath", whereas Jesus was crowned with a "crown of thorns"